# Take Multidimensional list and concat the similar

Tags: python-3.x

I have 2-D list where each item of the list contain and id and an error with it. i have to concat all the errors if they comes in consecutive lines.

```
inputList=[["12","hello"],["12","hello"],["12","hello"],["13","hi"],["13","hi"],["12","hello"]]
outputList=["hellohellohello","hihi","hello"]
```

Comment: What have you tries so far? Please show you effort along with errors you have encountered

Comment: use list comprehension https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_lists_comprehension.asp